# Siddhi Query Language 'and' operator

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I was testing the usage of the 'and' operator and used the example mentioned in the documentation:

```
from every a1 = OrderStock1[action == "buy"] and 
                a2 = OrderStock2[action == "buy"] -> 
                b1 = StockExchangeStream[price > 70] -> 
                b2 = StockExchangeStream[price > 75] 
select  a1.action as action, b1.price as priceA, b2.price as priceB
insert into StockQuote partition by stockSymbol
```

I have noticed that if no event is sent to the OrderStock2 stream, a matching still happens.

The definition of 'and' in the documentation is : the occurrence of two events in any order. My understanding is that for a match to happen both OrderStock1 and OrderStock2 should receive events in any order followed by 2 events received in StockExchangeStream satisfying the price condition.

Any explanation of why a match happens even if no event is sent to the OrderStock2 stream??